# modify the Source code of hadoop command to add text during command execution

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'd like to see the source code for certain hadoop commands like -put and -ls. I want to be able to add additional information to the log outputs that are associated with running these commands. For example, i want to show the message "Hii user, your file is copying from local file system to hdfs" during the execution of -get or copyFromLocal command.

I want to change in core files not in api files like copyCommand.java(http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java?view=markup)

[this type of message should print on execution of command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWKu7.png)

Can anyone tell which file I should change.

How can I find these?

Comment: Hadoop shell related source is in [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell)

Comment: Thank you. I want to change code in core files. Hadoop shell which you refer is like API files. Please suggest which source file I need to edit?